# CircularFLO doesn't apply styles for live text

Tags: conversion, html, epub, indesign

I do conversion with CircularFLO from `.indd` to `.epub`. The problem is that live text doesn't pick up styles. I have live text in my document but it is always `Times New Roman`. What am I missing?

See the [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ov0r01koxf8nd59/u4j7fsBVbD/CircularFLO#lh%3anull-LiveText.png) in dropbox of live text, where the text loses its style and position. This [picture](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ov0r01koxf8nd59/u4j7fsBVbD/CircularFLO#lh%3anull-EmbeddedText.png) using embedded text does not.

Comment: Is Times Roman specified in the EPUB (did you check the CSS), or is it caused by your IPAD book viewer program (which might still mean there is nothing specified in the EPUB).

Comment: - Yes, TimesNewRoman is specified in .html pages. But there is also GothemLight in html folder inside of the archive https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ov0r01koxf8nd59/fcjv4yJias/CircularFLO/ebook_1024_699.zip
I noticed that on page 7 are different fonts.

Answer (score 1):

Please contact help@circularsoftware.com for free support.

The fonts used in your InDesign documents for live text must be TrueType or OpenType and must be active across the entire Mac and not just for InDesign.